# Remove ConcurrencyStamp updates on each migration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

In my .NET (Core 5) project with EF Core (6.0.3), I have the `Role` class, defined like this:

```
public static readonly List<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> RolesClaims = GetRolesClaims();

[...]

private static List<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> GetRolesClaims()
{
    return new List<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>
    {
        new() { Id = 1, RoleId = "admin", ClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role, ClaimValue = "admin" }
    };
}

[...]

public class RoleClaimConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> builder)
    {
        builder.HasData(Defaults.RolesClaims);
    }
}
```

The problem is that for every migration updates its ConcurrencyStamp in the `Up` and `Down` generated methods.

```
    migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
        schema: "dbo",
        table: "Roles",
        keyColumn: "Id",
        keyValue: "admin",
        column: "ConcurrencyStamp",
        value: "1e0c5e0e-a1a5-4131-9467-5df4b387b48f");
```

Is there a way to get rid of this noisy update?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a call to `Guid.NewGuid` in that `GetRolesClaims` method? I had a `DateTime` property that I initialised with `DateTime.Now` and that caused an update with every migration too, because EF saw the value changing. I suggest that you generate an arbitrary `Guid` value and hard-code that, rather than generating it on demand. That's what I did with my `DateTime` value.

Comment: the GetRolesClaims method is as is, nothing more

Comment: My apologies. I clearly didn't read carefully enough. It's actually the `Roles` table that's being updated so you must be providing the data for a `Roles` record somewhere. Are you providing data for that "admin" role and, if so, are you providing a `ConcurrencyStamp` value and, if so, how are you doing it?

Comment: @John, I do anything on Roles in the current migration, just this update is kept in any migration I do, the Roles data does not move from the beginning there is only one admin, and one regular user without a role

Comment: @John, I provide data for that admin role, the code is in the OP: the value from the `GetRolesClaims` function goes as seeded data in the `Configure` method.